# Welding a field to a content part

Tags: c#, orchardcms

Is it possible to explicitly weld a field to a content part in Orchard? I want that the field is **always** there, and can't be removed from the part.

For a content type you can do the following in a handler:

```
Filters.Add(new ActivatingFilter<SomePart>("SomeType");
```

Is it possible to do this with a field attaching to a part? I tried the following but this doesn't seem to work:

```
public class CalendarEventDefinitionPartHandler : ContentHandler
{
    public CalendarEventDefinitionPartHandler(IRepository<CalendarEventDefinitionRecord> repository)
    {
        Filters.Add(StorageFilter.For(repository));

        OnActivated<CalendarEventDefinition>(WeldFields);
    }

    private void WeldFields(ActivatedContentContext context, CalendarEventDefinition part) {

        // Make sure the fields are always on the part

        part.Weld(new DateTimeField
        {
            PartFieldDefinition = new ContentPartFieldDefinition("StartDateTest")
        });
        part.Weld(new DateTimeField
        {
            PartFieldDefinition = new ContentPartFieldDefinition("EndDateTest")
        });
    }
}
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: I guess your problem is [this](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/issues/5197)

but jtkech works on it [here](https://github.com/OrchardCMS/Orchard/pull/5721)